# Can travis-artifacts be used to upload to S3 from a pull request?

Tags: travis-ci

I have an org repo at [github.com/numenta/experiments](http://github.com/numenta/experiments), and a forked version at [github.com/rhyolight/experiments](http://github.com/rhyolight/experiments). When trying to get artifact uploads to S3 working [as described in this blog post](http://about.travis-ci.org/blog/2012-12-18-travis-artifacts/), I used the `travis encrypt` command to do this with the `-r rhyolight/experiments` option, and it worked, as you can see [on line 60 in the travis output](https://travis-ci.org/rhyolight/experiments/builds/10383034#L60).

I created a pull request against the [original repo](http://github.com/numenta/experiments), and the build [failed there](https://travis-ci.org/numenta/experiments/builds/10381436#L65) with the error:

```
Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
```

That tells me that travis was unable to decrypt the secure environment variables, probably because this is being executed in a different repository than where the hashes were created. Ok, that makes sense. So I recreated the secure variables with the `-r numenta/experiments` slug instead of using my own github username. So, I get a [familiar upload error](https://travis-ci.org/rhyolight/experiments/builds/10383574#L58) when the build runs on `rhyolight/experiments`, which I expected, but I also get the [same upload error](https://travis-ci.org/numenta/experiments/builds/10383576#L71) when it runs against the `numenta/experiments` from within a pull request.

To experiment, I merged the pull request to see if the secure values would be extracted properly once they were merged into master and no longer running from a pull request... [and it worked!](https://travis-ci.org/numenta/experiments/builds/10384950#L61)

Is there any way to publish artifacts with the travis-artifacts project from within a pull request to another repository?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chatting with support at Travis, the answer is no.